# Building a query for a reservation database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database which holds car reservations. I'm trying to write a query that will give me enough information to fill a view with the following properties:

1. Prior months (up to 3) i.e. in January the rows would be Dec, Nov, Oct
2. The location with the most reservations that month.
3. The number of reservations at that location, that month.
4. The total number of hours reserved at the location that month.

The reservation tables is laid out as follows:

```
ResID, PickUpDateTime, ReturnDateTime, LocationName, VehicleSno
```

I've been trying for two hours now to work it out, but I'm stumped. I have the COUNT(*) statement to get the number of hours from each location, but it's a little off because it's not limited by the month it's supposed to pertain to. :/ I really hate dates.

```
SELECT
    MONTH(PickupDateTime) AS Month,
    LocationName as Location,
    COUNT(*) AS NoOfRes,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, PickUpDateTime, ReturnDatetime) AS Hours   
FROM
    Reservation   
GROUP BY
    Location   
ORDER BY
    NoOfRes DESC
```

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far.

Comment: *sniff*.. *sniff* ... I smell homework ;)

Comment: I smell work, work.
What I have, thought it is way off...
`CREATE VIEW Report2 AS SELECT LocationName as Location, COUNT(*) AS NoOfRes,     TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, PickUpDateTime, ReturnDatetime) AS Hours FROM Reservation GROUP BY    Location ORDER BY NoOfRes DESC`

Comment: If you are facing difficulties with the month part: To get the month of a date, you can use the [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there, formatted nicely.

Comment: what did you expect to show if a car was booked out in Feb and returned in March ? should the hours be split between both months or all all into the first ?

Comment: There is a 48 hours limit, but that is a good question... hmm.. I suppose I would tick it to Feb, as that is when it was technically rented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the month of a date, you can use the [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function.

So, to get the The location with the most reservations for the month of Feb,

```
select LocationName, count(*) num_reservations
  from reservation
 where month(PickUpDateTime) = 2 --This can be parameterized if needed
 group by LocationName
 order by num_reservations desc
```

Comment: Thank you. A step in the right direction. I suppose I should just break the problem into multiple queries. Now, with this, I can make another query to calculate the total of hours registered that month.